# How to convert the result of the complete square form under the quadratic radical into the form of absolute value?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

such as：

```
Sqrt[(c + a x0 + b y0)^2/(a^2 + b^2)]
```

How can we get the following results?

```
Abs[c + a x0 + b y0]/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
expr = Sqrt[(c + a x0 + b y0)^2/(a^2 + b^2)]
Assuming[Element[{c, a, x0, b, y0}, Reals], Simplify[expr]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is because $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ when $x$ is assumed real.

Comment: ```expr = EuclideanDistance[{0, 2}, {3, 2}] - 
   EuclideanDistance[{0, -2}, {3, 2}] == 
  EuclideanDistance[{0, -2}, {x, y}] - 
   EuclideanDistance[{0, 2}, {x, y}]
Assuming[Element[{x, y}, Reals], Simplify[expr]]```Is there any other way to set parameters to real numbers?

Comment: @csn899  What is wrong with what you did? You told Mathematica to assume `x,y` are reals. I am not clear what is the issue you are facing.